# Configuration of sap-ushell-config for themes

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

By below code the ushell bar is created:

[image: ushell bar]

Now I need to edit profile settings for more themes:

[image: settings dialog for themes]

How to add more themes on that dialog box of ushell-config and render it to the screen?

I tried to change the ushell-config code but I didn't find any kind of results for adding themes on the setting button dialog box as my requirement was to add more horizon themes and dark themes in the dialog box except it was only showing one theme as a default.

Code:

[image: code image of ushell-config]

Comment: Although the question is clean and it is valid. What are you trying to accomplish? A) Test your app in another theme B) Make sure a theme is available when running your app C) Hosting your own launchpad somewhere or D) Other. This is usually found in test files and if it's A or B the approach will be different. Could you please clarify?